# Remove malware caused by mediabuntu.org

Tags: malware

OK, I think I did something wrong. I executed:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list
```

And now I can't access the Ubuntu Software Center.  So I tried to remove the file medibuntu.list and found that I don't have permission even when I try to do so via root.  The properties for this file show grayed-out access windows for Owner, Group, and Others.  It shows the Owner is root, but only allows read and write, and tells me that I am not the owner and so can not change permissions.

Comment: Did you install anything from medibuntu? Use `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` to delete the file. But this may not solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry how did that install "malware"?  "and tells me that I am not the owner and so can not change permissions."  You do not understand permissions it seems to me?! If the system wants you to become root... you need to become root to edit the file. 1 method would be using "sudo -i"  but do read up 1st on what it is you need to do. removing it from command line does not have to be the only method, You can also use the GUI (software&updates lets you edit those too)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing about the situation you described suggests the presence of malware, so unless there is something else going on that you have not shared, you can calm down about that.

What you are describing is actually correct behavior in Ubuntu. Your normal user cannot perform administrative tasks on the system unless you grant it temporary elevated privileges. This is why, for example, Software Center asks for your password to install new applications. It must use your password to temporarily elevate its privileges, allowing it to make system level changes (in this case, install new software).

The command you ran begins with `sudo`, which means "do this as the super user (root)". When you ran this command, you were asked to input your password. This granted elevated privileges to `wget`, and it downloaded and wrote the file *as the super user*, not as your normal user. If you want to change file permissions or delete the file, you will have to do that action as the super user by putting `sudo` in front of your command.

For example, if you are sure you want to delete that file, you could use this command in the terminal:

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list`

You may benefit from this additional reading:

- [Understanding File Permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)
- [Understanding root and sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)